# .so file has unexpected e_machine: 62 (EM_X86_64)

Tags: android, shared-libraries

i created a shared library using c++ in vsc. The following commands are used to build the shared library (.so file)

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -I. -c Encrypt.cpp
g++ -shared -o libencrypt.so Encrypt.o
g++ -Wall -I. -c main.cpp
g++ -o test main.o -L. -lencrypt -l:libcryptopp.a
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
./test
```

I implemented the libencrypt.so in my android project inside `src/main/jniLibs/<architectures>` which are `x86, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a`

Then in my `app/build.gradle` i included the ff:

```
ndk {
     abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
}
```

And finally my MainActivity.java

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("encrypt")
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //tv_cipher.text = encryptString("test")
    }

    external fun encryptString(plaintext: String): String
}
```

Error thrown: `libencrypt.so" has unexpected e_machine: 62 (EM_X86_64)`

Note: I am using a Ubuntu 18.04 environment with 64 bit when creating the shared library.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it still happen if you  include the 'x64' ABI target in your project?

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes

Answer (score 2):

The error is perfectly clear: you compiled `libencrypt.so` for a single architecture (x86_64, or 64-bit Intel) and are trying to use it for ARM architectures (ARM7 and AArch64, to be precise).

You should instead [cross-compile your library](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems) for the different architectures.
The easiest way to do this is to rely on the [CMake build system](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake) that comes with the Android NDK and simply let *it* cross-compile your `libencrypt` files.
Alternatively, you can cross-compile `libencrypt` for every architecture separately and move it into the corresponding `jniLibs` subdirectory.

For example, for 64-bit ARM the cross-compile command would be:

```
aarch64-linux-android21-clang++ -Wall -fPIC -I. -shared Encrypt.cpp -o src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libencrypt.so
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Hi @Botje how can i tell NDK that my Encrypt.cpp is dependent to other external library? I am using Crypto++ specifically modes.h

Comment: There is a [cryptopp-cmake](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake) project whose cmake file you can include in yours.